# Google Search Console: Fetch-and-Render fails on random resources

Tags: google-search-console

It successfully fetches page itself, but then breaks on whatever page tries to load: images, styles, fonts, js files, API calls – whatever. Every time something different. And it says that resources are "Temporarily unreachable".

And sometimes it successfully loads and renders entire page with no errors.

Their doc says that "Temporarily unreachable" means that either server took too long to respond, or that fetch was cancelled "because too many consecutive requests were made to the server for different URLs".

The page I tested is completely loaded within 1.5-2s. Is it too long?

It makes 20 requests: 1 html, 4 css files (3 of them are 3-party font-face), 6  js files, 4 api calls (1 failed, it's intentional), 4 font files, 1 image. Total data size is 2.5Mb. Is it too much?

I checked every failed resource with their "robots.txt tester" – each of them is allowed for googlebot.

I don't have any noindex/nofollow directives nowhere on the site.

And I remind, that sometimes it just succeeds, like everything is ok.

With all of that, I have 3 questions:

1. **Do I have to care of google's rendering at all?** If I will just pre-render my html (with phantomjs or whatever) for googlebot, won't it be enough for normal indexing?
2. If I need google's rendering – **do I have to care of that random fails?** If at least sometimes fetch-and-render succeeds, maybe, it means that my site will be indexed normally?
3. If I have to care about that fails – **what else do I have to do to make it work stably?!** Such random behavior doesn't make any sense and doesn't give me any clues about that.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to see this related post:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/118727/what-else-can-i-test-when-troubleshooting-a-fetch-issue-in-google-search-console/118730#118730

My thinking is that the failed API call may have some bearing, or more likely, DNS or shared hosting issues because of the randomness of your Fetch results. Some people have reported better performance when having a robots.txt file (even if empty or just User-agent: * ), and others have found that it was just overuse of the fetch tool on their domain.